# How do we perform operations on SQL binary data type?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi all is it possible to do arithmetic operations on MySQL / SqlServer binary data type?

For example, I have 256-bit values stored within a column.

And I want to select values between `10000000000` (1024) and `10011010100111110101` (633333).

Do databases provide this functionality?

Or is storing it as 4 64-bit integer column the only way to select a range from x to y?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant i don't go schools

Comment: What is the the real world use case you are trying to solve with every 5th digit offed?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant for the second example, it is a question to see if there are inbuilt mysql functions that could achieve it. but i'm sure you can find real world use cases for the first question

Comment: I might not be reading it right, but does `BETWEEN` do what you want? (ref: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm)

Comment: @normalocity yes effectively what I want is a `between` that works for binary types.

Comment: @Pacerier Did you solved your issue?

Comment: @Lucio, still unsolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Binary datatype'/ binary object/ BLOB is opaque to the database, by definition. If you use this type it's up to the *application* to process it.

If you want the database to process/index/query your data, pick a datatype it understands. For SQL Server, BIGINT is 8 bytes (64 bits) and NUMERIC can go to 38 digits (~ 126 bits). In MySQL, DECIMAL/NUMERIC can go to 64 or 65 digits (~ 212 bits).

And if you do actually have a real requirement here, you can "factor out" the actual significant segments into their own columns & query on those.

In the most blunt & uninformed workaround case, that could be dividing your 256-bit chunk into 2 or 4 words;  but if you have any kind of real requirement, you should be able to identify more specific sections which are of business interest.